# How can I use "like" functionality of Sql in cakephp code

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Hi I have a code in which I am sending a keyword in URL so when we click on link its going to our website so for that I am checking what keyword value is coming in URL in my controller

```
$keyword= $this->params['url']['keyword'];

$dUsers = $this->Db_user->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions'=>array('Db_user.area_of_expertise'=>$keyword),
        'order'=>array('Db_user.last_name'=>'asc')
    )
);
```

So my databse has keywod value like : ab
ab,bc,ca
ab,cd
so what is happening by this its giving only ab keyword in result but I need all 3 result which have my keyword in DB
so for it I tried to make it like

```
'Db_user.area_of_expertise'=>'%keyword%'
```

also tried:

`Db_user.area_of_expertise'=>'%'.keyword.'%'`

But after it getting no results.

Comment: not familiar with cakephp , but i guess u need multiple `keywords` as `argument`. Why not simply use OR condition. for example, `condition1 %keyword%`  OR  `condition2 %keyword%` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use in your conditions array:

```
'Db_user.area_of_expertise LIKE' => '%'.keyword.'%'
```

Comment: I would also suggest reading the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) or, better, using [cakeDC search plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search)

Answer (score -2):

You could be using the query method for your custom queries find reference below
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Comment: why use `query` when you can do as @holt suggests? If you take a look at the link you provided you find than using query shuold be avoided if not necessary

Comment: You can use what ever you want. This is one way of doing a custom query or as @Holt suggested in your case.

Comment: `query` should be avoided because it does not automatically escape variables, which forces you to add extra check and function calls to manually do what Cake directly offers you with the others methods.